# Calling external JS and jQuery.min JS in tinymce editor's main js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE Editor and now want to use some other jQuery plugins in the editor.
e.g. I want to use custom scroller js to beautify the editor and also want to use SWFObject JS and jQueryUI inside the editor. For this, I may need jQuery.min also. I tried to use many ways to call these js files but no positive result.
Please suggest me the way(s) to get it achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Your production site should use the jQuery.min version as it has been minified but still contains all the "full fat" jQuery code. You should only use one version of jQuery to prevent problems with legacy code.

The answer is: minified = full. Use either.

The plugins you are using simply have a requirement to use jQuery (perhaps a particular version) but the way they call jQuery is like any other jQuery code - through your header.

Comment: I have used both jQuery and jQueryUI in my website, but I need scrollbar js, modernizr js, and some other js files inside the editor. So that I could improve the look-n-feel of content inside the editor.

Comment: Thanks but I know that I can use any of either minified or unminified js. My issue is that How should I call other js files to that editor

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. When you include jQuery from your document header it can be used throughout the entire document (page) UNLESS you are using iframes to load external content. If you include all your JS scripts in your header then they should all work as expected. What do you currently have? Do you have a live link so we can take a look?

Comment: Sorry but due to organizational policies, I can't share the website link with you.
I would be agree to the point you are saying if I won't be facing this problem. Actually, all the js/css files defined in the parent html are not applying to the html which is inside an iFrame. And, that's the thing which is creating all the problems.

Comment: Ok, so you are loading within an iframe. You need to add the JS files to the header of the HTML pages you are loading within the iframe - this problem is nothing to do with the parent page.

Comment: Yeah. But html document is loaded using scripts in a js file.
TinyMCE Editor uses a js (named tinymce.min) to create complete html document in an iframe. And, now everything that needs to do is to be done within that js file.

Comment: TinyMCE is bound to an element within a document (mainly a textarea) thus a normal HTML document is required... Take a look at the TinyMCE demos. Unless you're doing something completely bespoke but we need some demo code to go on...

Comment: I have seen all the demos and even searched google for many things in related to the concept. But, problem still exists.
Let's wait for another reply. May be someone else could give some idea of what to do.
And, thanks for your reply!!